# Magento 2 Get category id using category title

Tags: magento2, category, magento-2.0, filter, category-attribute

I would like get category id by only using category title by using this kind of function.

```
->load($categoryTitle, 'title')
->getId();
```

Use case: Get category id by title and put id data to array in migration script.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do it via collections:

First you need to inject a `CategoryFactory` in your class constructor.

Magento 2.0 & 2.1:

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
) {
    $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    parent::__construct(...);
}
```

Then anywhere else in your class you can do:

```
$collection = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('name',$categoryTitle)->setPageSize(1);

if ($collection->getSize()) {
    $categoryId = $collection->getFirstItem()->getId();
}
```

Magento 2.2:

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $collecionFactory
) {
    $this->_collectionFactory = $collecionFactory;
    parent::__construct(...);
}
```

Then anywhere else in your class you can do:

```
$collection = $this->collecionFactory
                ->create()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('name',$categoryTitle)
                ->setPageSize(1);

if ($collection->getSize()) {
    $categoryId = $collection->getFirstItem()->getId();
}
```

Comment: Got an error PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory::getCollection()

Comment: @kilis see my update, you need to use DI to inject that class ;)

Comment: For my use case i need this kind of function $collection = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory')         ->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('title',$categoryTitle)->setPageSize(1);

Comment: @kilis well it's bad practice to use the object manager directly, you should always use dependency injection

Comment: yeah i know. Our project upgrade script is designed like that :/

Answer (score 6):

This can be done using service contracts which are considered as best practice.

**Edit:** The original answer did not show the full paths to the included classes, I had to find the relevant namespaces, so updated the example slightly with a full class and namespaces.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Categories;

use \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryListInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroup;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder;


class CategoriesFilterSearchService
{
    protected $categoryList;
    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * @var FilterBuilder
     */
    protected $filterBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        CategoryListInterface $categoryList,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
    ) {
        $this->categoryList = $categoryList;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->filterBuilder         = $filterBuilder;
    }

    public function getNameCategory()
    {
        $enableFilter[] = $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::KEY_NAME)
            ->setConditionType('like')
            ->setValue(self::CATEGORY_NAME_HELP) // name of the category on const
            ->create();

        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
            ->addFilters($enableFilter)
            ->create();

        $items = $this->categoryList->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();

        if (count($items) == 0) {
            return FALSE;
        }

        foreach ($items as $helpCategory) {
            $CategoryId = $helpCategory->getId();
        }
        return $CategoryId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simple do it using **`name`**,

```
$title = 'womens';
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');

$collection = $_categoryFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('name',$title);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($collection->getData());
exit;
```

Comment: Not for FE use, upgrade script functionality needed.

Comment: you just have says title, i have updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try Below Code For Phtml File:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$_categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');

$categoryTitle = 'Outdoor'; // Category Name

$collection = $_categoryFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('name', ['in' => $categoryTitle]);

if ($collection->getSize()) {
    $categoryId = $collection->getFirstItem()->getId();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it with help from my collage

```
$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory')->create()->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToSelect('name')
        ->addFieldToFilter('name', ['in' => $categoryTitle]);
```

:)
Since the collection will only return the record you want you can grab the only result with `->getFirstItem()` on the above code

Answer (score 0):

To refactor that in a functioning script i suggest using the following

```
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$_categoryFactory = $obj->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$collection = $_categoryFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('title',$categoryTitle)->setPageSize(1);

if ($collection->getSize()) {
    $categoryId = $collection->getFirstItem()->getCategoryId();
}
```

**Edit:**
I made and tested a script. I created a file in /scripts/file.php

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

// Set the state (not sure if this is neccessary)
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$_categoryFactory = $obj->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$categoryTitle = 'Test';
$collection = $_categoryFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('name',$categoryTitle)->setPageSize(1);
if ($collection->getSize()) {
    $categoryId = $collection->getFirstItem()->getId();
    echo $categoryId; 
}
```

Comment: Tried your code , but changed first line to $obj = $this->_objectManager; Got an                                                   
  [Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]  
  Invalid attribute name: title    error

Comment: When you got that error you did not use my script.

Comment: I just added a fully tested script. please check that. it will work for sure!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to inject collection factory class

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $collecionFactory ) {
    $this->_collectionFactory = $collecionFactory;
    parent::__construct(...); }
```

After that inside your method, you can do this,

```
$categoryTitle = 'Men';
$collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToFilter('name',$categoryTitle)->setPageSize(1);

if ($collection->getSize()) {
    $categoryId = $collection->getFirstItem()->getId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `loadByAttribute`

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $this->_categoryFactory */
$category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->loadByAttribute('name', $name);
```

Answer (score -1):

I managed to write my own (more efficient) method:

```
$entityTypeId = \Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetup::CATEGORY_ENTITY_TYPE_ID;
$row = $this->queryF("SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `entity_type_id` = $entityTypeId AND `attribute_code` = 'name'", 1);
$nameAttributeId = $row['attribute_id'];
$categoryNames = $this->queryF("SELECT * FROM `catalog_category_entity_varchar` WHERE `attribute_id` = '$nameAttributeId'");
$this->categoryNameIdMap = [];
foreach ($categoryNames as $item) {
    $id = $item['entity_id'];
    $title = $item['value'];
    $this->categoryNameIdMap[$title] = $id;
}
```

This code caches all title:ids into an array, and only query 2 times.

Worked for me. Easier to use!