# How to get names, IDs and details of my categories without falling in to bad practice?

Tags: magento2, category, best-practice, object-manager

It's been commonly accepted you should never use `\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()` I can link sources explaining why [if needed](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly/117101?noredirect=1#comment294827_117101). Given this how would I go about getting the names of my categories if I should never use `\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()`? Thanks.

EDIT: I don't just want category names I'd like IDs and various other bits of information for each but names is a good start

Comment: check [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/115121/20064) , it follows the best practice

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I was looking for @Piyush how do i close my own question?

Comment: You can answer it and mark the answer accepted or delete it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the comments to the original question if you need a solution to my problem

```
    public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $collecionFactory
) {
    $this->_collectionFactory = $collecionFactory;
    parent::__construct(...);
}
```