# Magento2 : Get Category Ids from product import csv

Tags: category, import, magento-2.2.5

product import csv containing category data which is given as below

> Default Category/Diagrams/Business,Default
>   Category/Diagrams/Strategy,Default Category/Diagrams/Planning,Default
>   Category/Diagrams/Marketing,Default Category/Diagrams/Icons

I want to fetch category ids from the above string.

Answer (score 0):

please check in

> /var/www/html/magento231/vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product.php

find  **_saveProducts()** method:

in  **while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch())**

you will ($bunch) get data bunchwise

get category title from it and apply below soultion in it:

[Magento 2 Get category id using category title](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115118/magento-2-get-category-id-using-category-title)

Answer (score 0):

I would have said something more like this.  Want to explode string.

```php
$strings = explode("/", "Default Category/Diagrams/Business,Default Category/Diagrams/Strategy,Default Category/Diagrams/Planning,Default Category/Diagrams/Marketing,Default Category/Diagrams/Icons");

$categoryIds = [];
foreach($strings as $string) {
    if($id = $this->getCategoryTitleFromId($string)) {
        $categoryIds[] = $id;
    }
}
```

Your method to load ID by string will look like this

```php
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory 
) {
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory ;
}

public function getCategoryTitleFromId($title) {
    $collection = $this->collectionFactory 
        ->create()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('name', $title)
        ->setPageSize(1);

    if ($collection->getSize()) {
        return $collection->getFirstItem()->getId();
    }
    return null;
}
```